# How to fetch text from dynamically changing string

Tags: vbscript, substring

Every day I am receiving values as given below, since to automate I want fetch last part of the string from a text. For example, from the following

> a) 999999000045090
>   b) 9990090105
>   c) 9999010000
>   d) 990000660000

from the above I need to fetch actual values in the right as given here

> a) 45090
>   b) 90105
>   c) 10000
>   d) 660000

since the length is varying and not fixed I need help to resolve

Comment: Which programming language are you using? Are the letters part of the strings you receive, or just the numbers? Do you receive 1 multiline string or 1 string per line?

Comment: Hi, I am using VBScript. I receive the text in a file like 999999000045090   in each file

Comment: Hi, I am getting 999999000045090 at the end of file and I am able to fetch and store in a variable , after that I have to fetch the right part, 45090 is the count of records processed in that file. I have to fetch it and send. I am trying to automate. The problem is the 9 and 0 is varying everyday , if only  1 record is processed then it would be 999999000000001, so I have to fetch 1. I am trying to do using VBScript

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression:

```
Dim inputString, regularExpression, outputString
inputString = "999999000045090"
Set regularExpression = New Regexp
regularExpression.Pattern = "^9+0+"
outputString = regularExpression.Replace(inputString, "")
```

`^` will match the start of the string, `9+` will match 1 or more nines and `0+` will match 1 or more zeroes.

Which means that, in this example, `9999990000` will be replaced by an empty string, and that `outputString` will be `45090`.

Disclaimer: not tested. I am not familiar with VBScript.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner Thanks for the advice about the `Set` keyword. I removed it from the 2nd line of code. But please put your code in an answer of your own.

Comment: @Chs If the answer helped you, you can accept it and/or upvote it.